# What's the easiest way to Import a CSV file into a Django Model?

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-forms

I am making an app in DJANGO that deals with a lot of 'questions'. There is a question table specified in Model and there will be more or less thousand of questions.

Now, I have an excel file in hand where all the questions are and I can make a CSV file from there. I just need to get the CSV data in my question table. 
What could be the possible easiest way to do that? Can anyone tell about any tool, process, code to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it with a view using `csv` module. Here is an example of how I create bulk amount of users. This may not be the most efficient way to do it but it sure gets the job done.

```
import csv
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def create_bulk_user(request):
    with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media', 'core', 'employees.csv')) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
                username=str(row[0]),

                defaults={
                    'password': make_password('ddff123#'),
                    'first_name': ' '.join(row[1].split()[:-1]),
                    'last_name': str(row[1].split()[-1])
                }
            )
            designation, created = Designation.objects.get_or_create(
                name=str(row[4]), defaults={}
            )
            department, created = Department.objects.get_or_create(
                name=str(row[3])
            )
            user.profile.designation = designation
            user.profile.department = department
            user.profile.proximity_id = str(row[2])
            user.profile.save()

    context = {}
    return render(request, "core/create_bulk_user.html", context)
```

Keep in mind that there is a `bulk_create` method for you to use but I haven't used that over here.

Comment: nicely done. But Can you refer any package/module with more control (i.e. admin control, preview from admin panel etc.)?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. But please share it over here if you find anything on Google.

Answer (score 11):

A [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) may be the best option for importing this data into your database. It gives you access to Django's ORM whilst being separate from the request/response cycle. You can call it from the command-line with your .csv file as an argument.

Here's a simple example.

```py
import csv
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from app.models import Question

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Load a questions csv file into the database'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--path', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path = kwargs['path']
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
            for row in reader:
                Question.objects.create(
                    attr1=row[0],
                    attr2=row[1],
                )
```

If you saved it as `app/management/commands/load_questions.py` you would invoke it as:

```sh
python manage.py load_questions --path /path/to/your/file.csv
```

Comment: That is a nice idea but I also need to specify everytime which model I need to update.. and it will be tough if there are so many models to date in regular basis. Can you refer any package/module with more control (i.e. admin control, preview from admin panel etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

A SQL client with an "import" button seems to be the obvious choice e.g., SQLiteStudio for SQLite or MySQL Workbench for MySQL.

However, if that doesn't work, you can also do this in a single line using the pandas library:
`pd.read_csv(filename).to_sql(tablename, con)`

[to_sql documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)